# Building a PC for Storage Purposes?

Tags: storage

I am looking to build a system primarily for storage purposes at my Home. I have a high end laptop for work, so won't use this much or at all for doing any processing intensive task. Here is what I want to do. A P4 (it will be cheap, and I don't need too much processing), with 1 GB RAM and 2 Hard Disks of 2 TB Each (Internal). The PC will be connected to Internet via Wi-Fi dongle and/or ethernet.

What I want to ask is, if there are any limitations to storage based on processing and RAM. And if yes, at max upto what?

Any Suggestions?

PS: This system will be Storing my Media Collection from my Laptop and other devices, and syncing some of it with online storage. The system is required to run 24x7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a P4 for an always-on server would be very expensive in energy use (something like [150W to 200W peak](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-cpu-power-consumption,1750-9.html)) compared to an Intel Atom (15W to 40W) - each watt equates to about $1 to $1.50 in electricity per year, and a significant amount of CO2 emissions.

If you want to build a system, use a low-cost Atom motherboard - recent models support 64-bit and dual-core, and the motherboard comes with an Atom CPU, so the total cost should be less than $100 for motherboard and CPU (like [this example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041RSC94)).   A modern system will also properly support [Wake on LAN](https://superuser.com/questions/86576/how-does-wake-on-lan-work) (WOL) - with care, the server can be in S3 Sleep mode (standby) most of the time, only waking up when you need to access it.

Using a pre-built NAS is a good idea - these typically use ARM processors which also have very low power consumption.

Even if you don't care about power consumption, every watt of power consumed must be dissipated by cooling fans on the CPU and in the case, so a P4 based server will be very noisy - as I experienced before I dumped a P4 based NAS build for an Atom build.

Comment: I guess if you really want to use the existing hardware it may be worth seeing if your bios will let you underclock the CPU, also make sure you strip out any extra un-needed hardware like graphics cards.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend a cheap consumer NAS device.  They are quite full-featured these days, and a lot simpler and cheaper than building a PC, especially when you consider energy to costs to keep them running.

If you persist with building a system, look for something that will do RAID 1 for data safety (the same advice applies to the NAS enclosure), and then make sure you also have a way to keep a real backup. Since this sounds like the kind of data that won't change often, it may just mean burning another pair of DVDs (one to keep handy at home and one to keep somewhere else)  once a week or so with the new data, or it might mean something much more complicated.

Also, you'll definitely want to opt for a wired connection.  Wireless works fine for simple web browsing and some other tasks, but you'll find the throughput lacking for large file transfers compared to wired, especially if you're sharing the airspace with the device on the other end of the transfer.

Comment: Will NAS be able to sync some of the files to Web on its own without help of any external system?

Comment: If the NAS supports rsync it would be able to sync with another linux server which could be running a webserver. What are you planning to do?

Comment: I have around 400 GB High-Res Photographs which are right now stored in external HDD. Also, I work as a freelancer so have a lot of my clients stuff scattered here and there on DVDs. And lastly, lot of movies purchased on DVDs. I want to put all these things at one place, and sync the first two (Photos and Backups) with Backblaze for extra security.

Comment: Good point - many of the NAS-es are actually UN*X boxes inside, and often customizable (e.g. I have a Synology DS211j, and it has a built-in SSH access to Linux shell, `ipkg`-based package system etc.); it can be easily adapted to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the expense of a dedicated NAS box, you might want to look at [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/). I installed this in a VM the other day to try it out, and the install was very smooth with [these instructions](http://www.sysprobs.com/nas-vmware-workstation-iscsi-target). The only problem I had was that the newer version of FreeNAS needed a little more memory (512MB) than the older ones, which were happy with the default 256MB FreeBSD memory allocation.

The other option is to find a VM Appliance. There is a rather old VMware appliance for [FreeNAS 6](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/168), but someone has done what I did but released the image for [download](http://groups.google.com/group/ss4200/browse_thread/thread/13fcbfa39c74f03c).
Assuming you already have [VMware player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) installed, within a few minutes of downloading one of these appliances, you could be trying out the software yourself, with minimal time investment.

Finally, if you want to keep power usage to a minimum, you could always *under clock* your Pentium IV. If it's a high clock rate chip, you could seriously reduce it's power draw by clocking it at say 1.5GHz, which should be more than enough for a NAS box. This will have the knock on effect that it will need less cooling and thus could be much quieter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a few comments or suggestions on your requirements. If you would like to have this device around for a decade or longer, I would strongly suggest putting much more storage space than 4TB. But I only suggest that because you said you want it for media from your laptop. Now I'm also making some assumptions as to what "media" entails as you use it but I'm guessing maybe movies, TV shows, photos, and other videos. If that is correct, the price of hard drives are becoming so cheap that it would actually just be a waste to *only* put 4 TB into it. Is there any reason why you want 2x 2TB drives instead of a single? Because single 4TB drives are very affordable these days. I still suggest higher though and maybe start out with x1 20TB drive to last you as long as you need until you fill it up.

Now, these previous suggestions are only to take if you end up going the route of getting a dedicated PC to use for storage, but what I think may better serve you, especially since you said the main use you need it for is to host/store/share media from your laptop, is to dish out the money and invest in a good NAS - Network Attached Storage. With the quality of NAS devices out today, they're basically they're own storage server/computers- with no need to be ran from or connected to a computer to function. You can set these up to store media very easily onto it, share media very easily from it, and watch, open, browse, and share media from it very easily.

If you've never heard of a NAS or feel intimidated, dont worry at all. Theres so much documentation and tutorials and information online that you could never have knew what it was one day, and install and use one with all its abilities the next.

If you want more reviews or recommendations I would suggest going to Toms Guide and PCMag but Toms Guide usually gives everything one needs to know about anything.

As for a specific NAS, i would suggest a Synology device and to be more specific i would sugeest a Synology DS220+ for an entry level. It can hold 2 drives and take up to 6gb ram and they cost only $299 and Amazon has them available on Prime with 2 day shipping. You'll need to buy your hard drives to put in them though. And another very important note, if you go that route or whatever device you choose, go to their website and read through the documentation. Most of them have a list of acceptable hard drives they suggest. This way if you ever run into problems its makes it MUCH easier for them or someone to help you out.