# Wake On Lan to power on computer?

Tags: networking, remote, wake-on-lan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does wake on LAN work?](https://superuser.com/questions/86576/how-does-wake-on-lan-work)

I was wondering if it was possible to **turn on** a computer via WOL and if so what network card can do it? I can wake my computer from sleep no problem with my current network card but what I would really use the WOL for (as I never have my computer sleep) is to turn on my computer for some reason if it powers off or is accidently shut down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your motherboard has to support it. Along with your NIC, if it isn't builtin. Simple as that.

Edit:

You can either google your computer model, or restart your computer and go into the BIOS settings and look for a setting similar to "Allow wake by PCI devices", "Allow WOL", or "Power on by Alarm".

Comment: The "support" usually comes in the form of "Allow wake by PCI devices" or similar BIOS setting. (This seems to apply to integrated NICs as well.)

Comment: Ah yes, I should be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

To check for capability. The setting should be in your bios to enable or disable. Some more information about this setting in the OS, assuming windows 7:

http://windows7-issues.blogspot.com/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html

also note if its a laptop, you need to make sure the network card does not get turned off:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617165%28WS.10%29.aspx